# web api 2 not taking json request

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

In `MVC Web API` controller, `JSON` request parameter not working when it contains `[` and `]`

1. Headers having `application/json`

**Request Object**

```
public class Sample
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public DateTime Created { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public IHttpActionResult Test(Sample request)
{
}
```

This not accepts

```
[{
  Id: 1,
  Created: "22-02-2002"
}]
```

This accepts

```
{ 
  Id: 1,
  Created: "22-02-2002"
}
```

Comment: If you're sending an object, use `{}` without `[]`, if you're sending an array, use `[{}]`. It makes no sense why you would expect `[]` to work when it is not an array your controller accepts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to send an array of `Sample`s, then you need to do so at the parameter list.

```
public IHttpActionResult Test(Sample[] request)
{
}
```

Comment: It is not an array

Comment: The [] means array